# What is the etymology of “angiokeratoma”?

Tags: etymology, greek

What is the etymology of angiokeratoma?

> [An **angiokeratoma** is a benign capillary ectasia](https://dermnetnz.org/topics/angiokeratoma) in the superficial dermis that presents as an asymptomatic blue-red hyperkeratotic papule anywhere on the skin.
> Source: DermNet.org

I found that *angio*- means vessel. What does *-kera* mean?
Does *–toma* mean tumor?

Comment: You can look up the different parts of medical terms here on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_medical_roots,_suffixes_and_prefixes) - in angio-kerat-oma, the various parts are all from Greek.  I don't think this is a tumour though. Ask a doctor.

Comment: I wish I could access that link under Internet censorship

Comment: Try this link to an archive of the page: https://archive.fo/BVlIn

Comment: The idea of getting around the censorship is interesting. archive is not accessible either.

Comment: It saddens me to hear that there are places in the world that censor knowledge. Perhaps you could try to find an archive that isn't censored, or perhaps use a VPN to access the page. Other possibilities are to look up combining forms in a good dictionary - the OED online is one such dictionary, but unfortunately it's not free.

Comment: Try these links, these pages should be viewable publicly without a login to the OED.  [angio-](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00008439), [kerato-](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00126069), [-oma](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00163134).  Hopefully your country doesn't censor the OED.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for your empathy. I was very desperate when I started living under it. I am not doing any better actually, but just become a bit used to it. I hope I won't lose my desire to connecting with the world.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes I can access the OED links to the parts of the word. Does using https://www.oed.com/ require subscription with payment?

Comment: yes it's a subscription service.

Answer (score 3):

As correctly identified by the OP, **angio-** is from Ancient Greek  ἀγγεῖον  and refers to *vessels,* pots or urns. In this specific case, blood vessels.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/angio-), an etymology dictionary, provides this succinct  analysis

> **angio-**
> before vowels *angi-*, word-forming element meaning "vessel of the body," now often "covered or enclosed by a seed or blood vessel," from Latinized form of Greek *angeion* "case, capsule, vessel of the body," **diminutive of *angos*** "vessel, jar, vat, vase," which is of unknown origin. Beekes says "Possibly a Mediterranean loanword ..., as kitchen utensils are often borrowed."

**[keratoma](https://www.rxlist.com/keratoma/definition.htm#:%7E:text=Last%20updated%20on%20RxList%3A%203,frictional%20trauma%20to%20the%20skin.)**

> An area of hardened skin, usually called a *callus* which is usually a response to frictional trauma to the skin.

To understand its origin better, the medical term can be split into kerato– and –oma

**Kerato-** is derived from Ancient Greek κέρας meaning “horn” which is the hardened skin (also *callus*) often formed on the bottom of your foot (sole).

**–oma** is a suffix, it too is derived from ancient Greek -ωμα (-ōma) and refers to tumors or masses the latter which [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mass#Etymology_1) defines as “5. (medicine) A palpable or visible abnormal globular structure; a tumor.”